# Inserting a file input as an img in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, blob, same-origin-policy

Two part question...

Basically, at the end of the day, I want to have a `file` `<input>` and let the user select a picture file from their filesystem.  Then I want to display it back out on the page in an img tag.  I'll need to process it later, so I know `data:` isn't the road to be going down, which seems like it leaves `blob:`, which I can't figure out with my googlefu whether it's X-origin or not.

So is `blob:` considered X-origin?  If I have an `<img>`'s `@src` as a `blob:` URI, will I be able to `getImageData()` on it?

If so, then how do you carry all this out?  I imagine that if one knows how, it is probably very straightforward but again, my googlefu is failing me...

So:

- is `blob:` X-origin?
- if not, how does one derive a `blob:` URI from a `file` `<input>`'s contents?

Comment: Sorry, I posted an aswner I little that not responds exactly your question. So, is blob really important? What you want to do with that image? upload? display?

Comment: I believe a file is a blob. Try `URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0])`.

Comment: http://html5demos.com/file-api/ is also quite good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) to generate a `blob:`-URI from a `File` or `Blob` object:

Basic demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HGXDT/

```
​<input type="file" id="file">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<img id="preview">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL;
document.getElementById('file')​.onchange = function() {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
    console.log(url);
    document.getElementById('preview').src = url;
};​
```

Code to check whether the script suffers from the Same origin policy or not (answer: **it doesn't**). (actually, the page itself is not affected, because it created the `blob:`-URI, but other pages cannot draw the `blob:` URI on a canvas and use it):
http://jsfiddle.net/HGXDT/1/

```
<input type="file" id="file">
<img id="preview">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
​
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL;
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function() {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
    console.log(url);
    
    var img = document.getElementById('preview');
    canvasSOPTest(img, url);
};
// See console. SOP error has to show up
canvasSOPTest(new Image(), 'http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico?'+new Date());

function canvasSOPTest(img, url) {
    // Same Origin Policy check
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        console.log('Painting image...');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        console.log('Attempting to get image data');
        try {
            ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            console.log('Success! No errors');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is use the HTML5 File Api to display an image and then upload that image or else?

This is a good example of how use File Api to preview images.

http://html5demos.com/file-api/