# How should I send an image from a user to a directory with html5 js?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to set up a thing where I get an image from a user with an html file input, and then preview the given image when it's selected. Right now, I want to send the given image to a directory, display it, and then delete the file. I know how I would do this in node.js, but since I can't use node.js in the browser, I have no clue how to go about this. Here is how I would go about this in node.js:

```
window.onload = function(e) {
  const chooseImg = document.getElementById("myFile"), img = document.getElementById('imgPreview');
  //Event Listener
  chooseImg.addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
    //get the file name
    let imgPath = chooseImg.value.split('\\')[2];
    //Create the file in ./_temp/
    fs.open(`./_temp/${imgPath}`, 'w', function (err, file) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
    //Display the image
    img.src = `./_temp/${imgPath}`;
    //Delete the file
    fs.unlinkSync(`./_temp/${imgPath}`);
  }, false);
}
```

`chooseImg` is my  tag, and `img` is the `<img>` element where I want to display the image. I think I need to use Blobs, but I cannot figure out how blobs work or how to use them.

Comment: fs is Node right?

Comment: yes, fs is node. But since I don't know any other way to go about this, that's the only way I can express what I'm trying to do

Comment: You can't save files to a directory in the browser.

Comment: Check out something like this: https://www.javatpoint.com/expressjs-file-upload

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11708896